# ms access query expression field not accepting IIf expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

im trying to return 1 if null and 0 if not null and when i enter the expression this [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1hwL.png)
error pops up.
heres the expression i wrote :

```
IIf(IsNull([_characterType]); 0; 1)
```

[The database file](https://ucarecdn.com/2ba135c3-ce8d-47ec-93b2-0f03b0617560/) (i had to empty it for legal reasons)

(the database was in another language with special characters and i changed all of it to english, that may be the problem but i still dont know how to fix it)

i tried using comma instead of semicolon and got the same result.

when i enter the same exact expression in SQL view it works but when i switch to design view it breaks again.

i tried using external software to fix the database.

i tried importing all of the data to another newly made access file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your expression:

```
Abs(Not IsNull([_characterType]))
```